# MVC 3 Views not deployed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been working on a small project on recent delived ASP.NET MVC 3 RC. The issue is that when I try to deploy my website via File System, certain views of my website are not deployed.  The site gives me error when i copy same deployed site to my hosting. When I manually copy views to hosting, it works ok.

Now this thing is not breaking anything as such, just want to know that if I am missing something while deploying my site. I am not sure why few views are deployed and why not others. Seems very random to me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you created the app before RC (aka using our Beta) we had a bug in which we didn't mark the views as "Content". New apps using the RC have this bug fixed, but if you open an existing project, it doesn't automatically fix up the existing files.

To fix them, select the file and in the properties pane, set the Build Output to "Content".